# How to get the rendered view as a string in express.js?

Tags: express, node-html-pdf

I want to store the rendered view `res.render` as string to a variable and use [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) package to print pdf:

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = res.render('my_view', res.view_data); // not work

pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./foo.pdf'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the app instance of express application.

```js
var appInstance = express();
appInstance.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // Set this relative to your file
appInstance.set('view engine', 'pug'); // Or whatever your view engine is

appInstance.render("my_view", view_data, (err, html) => {

  pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./foo.pdf'));
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank! Btw, I just found that `appInstance` can also obtain via `res.app`.